# Blank screen in vue.js if not using created() life cycle hook or spread operator (...)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The following example gives me a blank screen ([jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/saitam/xj1q2md9/53/)). Even the parts which have nothing to do with the loop are not being rendered.

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="objectFromApi">
    run objectFromApi function
  </button>
  <div
    v-for="obj in myObject[0].results"
    :key="obj.id"
  >
    <p>
      {{ obj.message }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myObject: []
  },
  methods: {
    objectFromApi: function(){
        this.myObject.push(
        {
          "count": 5,
          "results": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "message": "object 1"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "message": "object 2"
            }
          ]
        }
      )
    }
  },
  //created() {
  //  this.objectFromApi()
  //}
})
```

Nevertheless it does work if:

1.) Either using `objectFromApi` function directly in the `created` life cycle hook (what I don't want!)

```
created() {
  this.objectFromApi()
}
```

2.) Or (without the use of `created` life cycle hook) if I go directly into the nested `results` array and spread the objects out like this (what I also don't want!)

```
this.myObject.push(
  ...{
    "count": 5,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/someurl/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "message": "object 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "message": "object 2"
      }
    ]
  }.results
)
```

When using option 2.) of course the `v-for` loop has to look different:

`v-for="obj in myObject"` instead of `v-for="obj in myObject[0].results"`

What is wrong with my initial example?

Comment: In your original example you never call `objectFromApi` so `myObject` is an empty array. As a result `myObject[0]` is `undefined` and you'll get an error trying to access `myObject[0].results`. You can't access the property `results` of an `undefined` value. You should wrap your `<div>` in a `<template v-if="myObject[0]">` or similar. You'll still get a 'blank screen', but only because you aren't rendering anything.

Comment: @skirtle Thx for the answer. I have forgotten to put other elements there. Please check the updated code with an independent button, which is not seen, because the screen is still blank.

Comment: Existence of button it the template doesn't change anything about the fact at the time template is 1st rendered `myObject[0]` is `undefined` so you get an error and blank screen. Read what @skirtle says one more time and try to think...

Comment: But why is the button rendered if I use the spread out operator? [see jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saitam/dzspwga0/2/)

Comment: @saitam Because in that example your `v-for` is looping over `myObject` directly so no error occurs. The error is caused by trying to access the `results` property of `myObject[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the component is first rendering the array `myObject` will be empty.

During rendering it attempts this:

```html
<div
  v-for="obj in myObject[0].results"
  :key="obj.id"
>
```

The value of `myObject[0]` will be `undefined`. Attempting to access the `results` property of `undefined` will result in an error. This error will cause rendering to fail. Nothing will be shown, even the parts that didn't fail.

There are various ways to fix this problem. You could prepopulate the data with suitable empty properties:

```js
data: {
  myObject: [
    {
      results: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Alternatively, as you've noted, you could change the loop to use `v-for="obj in myObject"`, changing `objectFromApi` accordingly to only store the `results` array in `myObject`. Even if you don't want that exact change some similar change is probably a good idea because the `[0]` part strongly suggests you've got a problem with your data model. The key thing here is that it avoids trying to access nested objects that don't exist. The use of the spread operator in your second example is largely irrelevant.

Or you could skip the loop in the template:

```html
<template v-if="myObject[0]">
  <div
    v-for="obj in myObject[0].results"
    :key="obj.id"
  >
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```